How to redirect unauthenticated users to another website?
I am implementing some kind of SSO using cookie sharing in an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I want unauthenticated users in my app website (e.g. app.company.com) get redirected to my SSO website in which logging in happens (e.g. sso.company.com/account/login).
How can I redirect them from the app website to the sso website with a return URL?
In the app website I have used:
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication()
       .AddCookie(options => options.LoginPath  = "https://sso.company.com/account/login");

(The parts about data protection are omitted)
But I get this error:

System.ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'.

It seems that the login path must be a local path. How should I redirect to another website?

You are missing some key concepts, most likely your sso is implementing some standard protocol, i guess SAML or OIDC. First exeman what the sso provides and then search for basic setup examples, heres one on oidc https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/architecture-scenarios/sso-for-regular-web-apps/implementation-aspnetcore

You can use the OnRedirectToLogin event in the configuration of the AddCookie method to implement custom redirection logic, and use context.Response.Redirect method to configure the redirection path. The following is a sample code for redirecting the Google login page. You can refer to it:
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, option =>
{
    option.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            var isUnauthenticated = !context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            if (isUnauthenticated)
            {
                var returnUrl = context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString;
                var encodedReturnUrl = Uri.EscapeDataString(returnUrl);
                var loginUrl = $"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?ReturnUrl={encodedReturnUrl}";
                context.Response.Redirect(loginUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri); 
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

When an unauthenticated user accesses a restricted page:


By this way, I can redirect the user to the Google signin page when the user is not authenticated, but it should be noted that you need to add the corresponding return URL parameters to your sso service.
